# Magento 2 Service Worker not registering in localhost

Tags: magento2

I have created a virtual host for my Magento site in my local
magento.site.local (my virtual host)

and I have also created a self-signed SSL certificate using OpenSSL and I have imported the certificate in chrome also.

but still, I am getting the URL as unsecure but it is showing https://magento.site.local and in this (https is in red and striked with a line horizontally) and shows unsecured.

in the console i am getting an error like this

`DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://magento.site.local') with the script ('https://magento.site.local/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.`

Answer (score 2):

In the latest versions of Chrome, you can enable SW like this by enabling this flag in chrome `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`

to test this in firefox you can use `devtools.serviceWorkers.testing.enabled` setting.

Comment: no still not working for chrome